# Preprocessor directive return value

Tags: linux, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I want to receive in my output value of variable `check`
 that was dfeined with `#define check something`
Is it possible to receive this value with some preprocessor directive?
for example something like this:
`#error check`

Comment: what? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Naveen I have somwere defined check (#define check something) with some value that i don't know actually and i want to check what value in check variable now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#error` directive is not macro-expanded. Nor is `#warning`.

- http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Diagnostics.html#Diagnostics
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8tk0xsk.aspx

This means that you cannot output preprocessor expressions using `#error` or `#warning`

The closest you can get to giving messages dependent on the values of preprocessor expressions is something like this:

```
#if (MACRO < 12)
#error MACRO was less than 12
#elif (MACRO >15 && MACRO < 19)
#error Another message about MACRO
#endif
```

See "Conditionals" in the documentation for more:

- http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Conditionals.html#Conditionals

Answer (score 1):

No.

Variables don't have values at compile time, only at run-time. The preprocessor doesn't operate at run-time, only at compile-time.

Also, the preprocessor doesn't parse the language, it only manipulates text. It doesn't know about your variable declarations.

Answer (score 0):

If you HAVE TO get its value, try to just pre-process the file which has potential error.

```
 for gcc: gcc -E
```

Then you can MANUALLY check what it was expanded to.